# MSFLEXGRID slow navigation between cells

Tags: vb.net, vb6, msflexgrid

I am using msflexgrid in my vb6 application, It do work fine,but if any cell has large content then the problem comes. the problem is that when we navigate in grid by using arrow buttons, navigation becomes very slow when the cell with large content comes to visible area.Otherwise it works fine. In this case i am not trying to open the cell content of grid,just navigating from one cell to another. So how this slow performance or slow navigation can be solved or improved?

Comment: was it helpful to you? )

Comment: @MikroDel what do you mean by "was it helpful to you? ) ".Is question is helpful?? you are saying

Comment: answer - have posted answer..

Comment: why have you accepted only 10 answers for your 72 questions?

Comment: Do you have SP6 installed?

Answer (score 2):

Set your `Redraw` property to `false`

And set it to `true` again after update completed.

Comment: The problem i have mentioned in my question is problem while we navigate between cells just by using arrow keys.The problem is not during updating.When we navigate between cells navigation becomes slow.

Answer (score 1):

I know that once I had set autosize column rows on and it caused massive speed issues. Now I leave auto-size off normally, turn it on breifly when the data first loads, and make it an option for the user via context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I setup a test harness using the Service Pack 6 (latest) version of the MSFlex grid control as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim s As String

    For j = 1 To 500
        For i = 65 To 122
            s = s & Chr(i)
        Next i
    Next j

    For i = 1 To 4
        For j = 1 To 10
            MSFlexGrid.Col = i
            MSFlexGrid.Row = j
            MSFlexGrid.Text = s
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

The MSFlex Grid control had 5 columns and 50 rows in my case.

This generates about 29K (58 chars * 500 repeats) of data per cell. I can navigate fairly quickly from cell to cell with this test harness. I would suggest that you ensure you are using the latest (SP6) version of the control.

If you are using the SP6 version and the amount of data that you are displaying in each cell is so large that it is still causing a performance issue I would suggest switching to another control.

Possibly integrate a 3rd party VB6 control or leverage something you've written in .NET and integrate into your VB6 form.